# How to search and update multiple levels of a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a model in mongodb that looks something like this...

```
{
    username: 'bob', 
    user_id: '12345',
    post: 'Hey everyone, this is my post',
    photoID: RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER, // each user has their own photoID
    comments: [
        {
            username: 'tom', 
            user_id: '54321',
            post: 'Hey everyone, this is comment 1',
            photoID: RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER, // each user has their own photoID
            responses: [
                {
                    username: 'bob', 
                    user_id: '12345',
                    post: 'Hey everyone, this is response 2',
                    photoID: RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER, // each user has their own photoID
                },
                {
                    username: 'will', 
                    user_id: '35791',
                    post: 'Hey everyone, this is response 2',
                    photoID: RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER, // each user has their own photoID
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            username: 'bob', 
            user_id: '12345',
            post: 'Hey everyone, this is comment 2',
            photoID: RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER, // each user has their own photoID
            responses: []
        }
    ]
}
```

On my site, everytime a user changes their profile picture, they get a new 'photoID', referencing the picture, so it can easily be displayed with their username above any posts they make. Because of this, when a user updates their profile picture and gets a new 'photoID', I need to be able to make a query to this 'Post' model that searches for any 'posts', 'comments' or 'responses' that were posted by 'bob'. I then need to update the photoID for that 'post', 'comment' or 'response'.

Is there a query I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two queries to do that task:

1. Update photoID in subdocuments:
   https://mongoplayground.net/p/jTb3qDxIHL1

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "comments.$[c].photoID": "NEW_RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER",
    "comments.$[].responses.$[r].photoID": "NEW_RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER",
  },
},
{
  multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "c.user_id": "12345",
    },
    {
      "r.user_id": "12345",
    },
    
  ],
  
})
```

2. Update photoID in document root:
   https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Bm4Oykz-1E

```js
db.collection.update({
  user_id: "12345"
},
{
  $set: {
    photoID: "NEW_RANDOM_GENERATED_NUMBER",
    
  }
},
{
  multi: true,
})
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I thought I would have to use 3 separate queries, but you're right it works in 2.